# How to understand default template argument in C++11?

Tags: c++, templates, types, default, default-arguments

Here is the example I got from C++ Primer ver5 Chapter 16:

```
template <typename U, typename F=std::less<U>>
int compare(const U& v1, const U& v2, F f = F())
{
    if (f(v1, v2)) return -1;
    if (f(v2, v1)) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

I am a little confused of the usage here:

```
typename F=std::less<U>
```

Based on my understanding, `typename F` refers to `F` is a kind of type here, how could we assign a function object `std::less` to it? If so, does it mean I can also do sth like `auto F = std::less<U>;` or `typedef F std::less<U>`?

Or maybe should I consider it as `using F = std::less<U>`?

Comment: `std::less<U>` is a type (like `int`). (so more similar to the alias usage).

Comment: `std::less<U>` is not an object, it's a type. `std::less<U>()` or `std::less<U>{}` is an object that you can call like `std::less<U>()(u1, u2)` or `std::less<U>{}(u1, u2)`

Comment: If it was only `template<typename U, typename F>`, would you understand it? The "assignment" is just list default arguments for functions: It sets `F` to a specific type if `F` is not provided as a template argument. That means you can use `compare<int>(...)` (and `F` is the type `std::less<int>`), or `compare<int, std:greater<int>>(...)` (for `F` to be the type `std::greater<int>`).

Comment: Please check the ["Member Functions" in document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), there is a member function. In your example, type `std::less` is used to construct an instance `f`, and next `f` is used to call `operator()()` to compare two elements.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Maybe this question is kind of stupid, can we assign type A to type B? Where can I find the defination of this operator "=" under the scenerio F=less<U>?

Comment: @YiqunCui No types are being assigned. That is just a default argument for the template parameter `F`, exactly in the same way that a default argument for a function parameter works, so that `compare<U>` is the same as `compare<U, std::less<U>>` by default (though template argument deduction could also deduce it to something else depending on context).

Comment: @user17732522 thank you very much for your detailed explanations. Like you mentioned, "it is exactly in the same way that a default argument for a function parameter works" But for example, if we have a function who has a user-defined class as parameter and also has a default argument, I think the the user-defined constructor will be called for the initialization of the default argument. However I did not the same way operator "=" used under the default template argument situation. Do I miss someting? thanks again

Comment: @LiuYuan thanks for your comments. But if we could use std::less to construct F, why VS does not allow me to do the following:  auto F = std::less<U>

Comment: @YiqunCui This is because you are trying to assign a type to a variable. You must be aware of that `std::less<U>` is just a instantiated class template, which is a type, and you are trying to assign it to `auto F`, which `auto` is used to specify the type of `F`, which `F` is a variable. If you use `auto f = std::less<int>();`, things will be OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how could we assign a function object std::less to it?

`std::less<U>` is not a function object, but a class type that acts as a function object type. See e.g. the [reference at cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less).

Comment: @YiqunCui • this only seems confusing and bewildering because you are new to this part of C++.  For those of us who have been working with this stuff for many years, experience has taught us that it's not just confusing and bewildering, it's also byzantine and hazardous.

Comment: @Eljay Lol I am trying to enjoy the complexity of C++ and the pain during the learning process